# Command Line arguments from a Cocoa App

Tags: cocoa, command-line, nstask

I know there is a lot of info out there on how to do this, but I was wondering if using NSTask is the best way to call command line arguments from a Cocoa App. Also, if I wanted to use something like "dns-sd ..." (something that doesn't end until interrupted or killed), would calling a kill on it using NSTask be the best way to close it?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you mean calling command line tools from a Cocoa app, not accessing command-line arguments for the running application?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use fork and execv().

Comment: Yeah, but that's exactly what `NSTask` uses (well, probably `fork` and `execve`), so why go to the bother of recreating `NSTask` functionality when it already exists for you?